# c Infinite loop error

Tags: c

The program builds properly, but I'm getting an infinite loop of random numbers and I'm not sure why. I

```
int getInt(void);
double getDbl(void);
void prnTitle(void);
void prnFooter(double gTotal);
void pause(void);
double getDblLimited(double lowerLimit, double upperLimit);
```

1. comment out the main when submitting milestone one
2. Your final milestone one should run perfectly with the following tester program.

To comment out the main() delete the next two characters after the arrow

```
int main (void)
{
    int iVal;
    double dVal;
    welcome();

    // testing prnTitle()
    printf("listing header and footer with grand total:\n");
    prnTitle();



    // Testing prnFooter()
    prnFooter(1234.5678);
    printf("listing header and footer without grand total:\n");
    prnTitle();
    prnFooter(-1);


    // Testing Pause() and clrKyb()
    pause();


    // Testing getInt()
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    iVal = getInt();
    printf("You entered: %d\n", iVal);


    // Testing Get Int Limited
    printf("Enter an integer between 10 an 20: ");
    iVal = getIntLimited(10, 20);
    printf("Your entered %d\n", iVal);


    // Testing Get Double
    printf("Enter a floating point number: ");
    dVal = getDbl();
    printf("You entered: %0.2lf\n", dVal);


    // Tesing Get Double Limited
    printf("Enter a floating point number between 10.00 an 20.00: ");
    dVal = getDblLimited(10.0, 20.0);
    printf("You entered: %0.2lf\n", dVal);



    printf("End of tester program for milestone one!\n");
    return 0;
    }


/* End Commenting out the main out*/

// implement your functions for milestone one down here:
void welcome(void)
{
    printf("---=== Grocery Inventory System ===---\n");

}

void prnTitle(void)
{
    printf("Row |SKU| Name \t | Price |Taxed| Qty | Min |  Total  |Atn \n");
    printf("----+---+--------------------+--------+-----+-----+-----+------------+|---\n");

}
void prnFooter(double gTotal)
{
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------\n");
    //float  gTotal = 1234.57;
    while (gTotal > 0)
    {
        printf("%12.21f", gTotal);
    }
}
void clrKyb(void)
{
    char b;
    while (b != '\n')
    {
        scanf("%c", &b);
    }

}
void pause(void)
{
    printf("Press <Enter> to continue...");

    clrKyb();

}
int getInt(void)
{
    //printf("Enter an interger:");
    int d;
    char c;
    scanf("%d%c", &d, &c);
    while (c != '\n')
    {
        printf("Invalid integer, please try again ");
        scanf("%d%c", &d, &c);
    }
    return d;
}
int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)
{
    int a;
    //printf("Enter an integer between %d and %d:", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    while (a <= lowerLimit || a >= upperLimit)
    {
    //  printf("Invalid value, %d < value < %d:", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        scanf("%d", &a);
    }
    return a;
}
double getDbl(void)
{
    double d;
    char c;
//  printf("Enter a floating point number:");
    scanf("%lf,%c", &d, &c);
    while (c != '\n')
    {
        printf("Invalid number, please try again ");
        scanf("%lf%c", &d, &c);
    }
    return d;
}

double getDblLimited(double lowerLimit, double upperLimit)
{
    double a;
    printf("Enter a floating point number between %f and %f:", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    while (a <= lowerLimit || a >= upperLimit)
    {
        printf("Invalid value, %f < value < %f:", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        scanf("%lf", &a);

    }
    return a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged to figure out where the infinite loop happens? In your main, place print statements to see where the code stops advancing.

Comment: sorry my bad. The error begins in void prnFooter after the print statement

Answer (score 0):

```
void prnFooter(double gTotal)
{
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------\n");
    //float  gTotal = 1234.57;
    while (gTotal > 0)
    {
        printf("%12.21f", gTotal);
    }
}
```

You never modify the value of `gTotal` inside the loop. If it was greater than 0 going into the loop, it will be greater than 0 for forever, thus the infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you and again I'm sorry I forgot to mention where the error occured

Comment: @ortz3 Np. Next time though, make sure you fully describe the problem. If this helped you, please up vote it and accept the answer.